# Ajax not working 1

Tags: php, ajax

I have this ajax code that does not seem to be working.  The code will not acknowledge a successful result it just keeps giving the else statement.  I ran the dologin.php and it successful returned 1  Thank You in advance.

```
             <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
            <script>
                var jq162 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#submit").click(function(){
                    var Username = $("#Username").val();
                    var Password = $("#Password").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "dologin.php",
                        data: "Username=" + Username + "&Password=" + Password,
                        success: function(result){
                            if(result=='1'){
                            $(document.location = '/reward/home.php');
                            }
                            if(result=='2'){
                                $(".errors").html("Contact Administrator<br>Please provide the following error code.<br>Error Code:101");
                            }
                            if(result=='3'){
                                $(".errors").html("Invalid Password");
                            }
                            else{
                                $(".errors").html("Incorrect Credentials");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                return false;   
                });
            })(jq162);
            </script>
```

Comment: 'does not work" is not a valid error message

Comment: Replace `data: "Username=" + Username + "&Password=" + Password` with `data: {Username: Username, Password: Password}`. Otherwise e.g. having a `&` in the username/password will break things. When passing an object, jQuery takes care about properly urlencoding your values.

Comment: `$(document.location = '/reward/home.php');` makes no sense. Remove the `$()` around it!

Answer (score 1):

You get the `else` case because you aren't using an `if/else` chain.  It is probably executing the correct statement for `1`, but later sees : `if result was 3 ? else...` and since it isn't 3, you get the else.  Use an if/else chain instead.  Also, remove the `$()` around `document.location = '/reward/home.php'`

```
if(result=='1'){
   document.location = '/reward/home.php';
}
else if(result=='2'){
   $(".errors").html("Contact Administrator<br>Please provide the following error code.<br>Error Code:101");
}
else if(result=='3'){
   $(".errors").html("Invalid Password");
}
else{
   $(".errors").html("Incorrect Credentials");
}
```

This is done more cleanly with a `switch`:

```
switch (result) {
  case 1:
    document.location = '/reward/home.php';
    break;
  case 2:
    $(".errors").html("Contact Administrator<br>Please provide the following error code.<br>Error Code:101");
    break;
  case 3:
    $(".errors").html("Invalid Password");
    break;
  default:
    $(".errors").html("Incorrect Credentials");
}
```